# LINQ to SQL: Check for existence of a generic entity in a generic Repository

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, generics, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have a generic repository as like that

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    DataContext _db;
    public Repository()
    {
        _db = new DataContext("connection string");
    }
    System.Data.Linq.Table<T> GetTable
    {
        get { return _db.GetTable<T>(); }
    }
    public T GetBy(Func<T, bool> exp)
    {
        return GetTable.SingleOrDefault(exp);
    }
    ....
}
```

**Is it possible to add a generic method to this repository to check for the existence of any entity** like that:

```
public bool IsExisted(T entity)
{
    ...
}
```

it is easy to write it in any repository

```
_productRepository.GetBy(p => p.Id == 5 // or whatever);
```

where the productRepository like this:

```
public class ProductRepository : Repository<Product>
{
    public ProductRepository()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

I came to this since i always want to check for the existence of an entity alot, so i don't need to write the same method in all repositories.

Comment: Just as a side note: `IfExisted` is a bad choice - it's past tense, so checking `IfExisted(...)` really means: it did exist - sometime in the past - but not anymore. What you want is `IfExists(...)` - this is **it exists NOW**.

Comment: @marc_s why this method - this way - will be past tense? i just want to be able to write something like `_productRepository.IsExisted(someproduct)` and is that means that all generic methods in this generic repository are all past tense?? sorry but i can't get it

Comment: That's just the way the English language is - `IsExisted` is past tense - it existed some time in the past - but not anymore. If that works for you - fine - but if some other developer looks at this code, he might get a wrong impression, based on the name of the method. For something that exists **now**, you should use `.DoesExist(...)` or just simply `.Exists()`

Comment: ok @marc_s, so what will be the right name since i didn't mean that.

Comment: I would just use `.Exists(....)` - then when you check in your code, it would look something like `if (repository.Exists(.....))` and that's very clean and very clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all your entities have for example a property Guid Id you can create the following interface for your entities:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And restrict your Repository class to it:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class, IEntity
{
   ....
}
```

You can then define the following function in your base repository:

```
public bool Exists(T entity)
{
    return GetTable.Any(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach will not work in LINQ to SQL because it won't know how to translate a call to the `IEntity.Id` property into SQL.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior but it works fine since i make all Entities implement `IEntity`

Comment: @MGA: While I can't test this to verify right now, I'm fairly certain it won't work. It will compile just fine, but you'll get an exception when you actually run it against your database.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, Actually I tested it against the database and it works with no exception, but how can you tell it won't know how to translate a cll to the `IEntity.Id` with `where T : class, IEntity` and all the entities are implementing the `IEntity`?? thanks for consideration

Comment: @MGA: I assumed LINQ to SQL would work that way because that's how LINQ to Entities works. Since it is possible to implement interface members explicitly, there is no guarantee that `((IEntity)entity).Id` is the same as `entity.Id`. So attempting to access it in a query expression like this causes an exception to be thrown in LINQ to Entities. Perhaps LINQ to SQL is implemented differently.

Comment: I have it running in production code for Linq to Entities and it works perfectly.

Comment: Evidently things have changed since I last had to do this. +1